# ArduinIO package Libraries' documentation

Tags: matlab, arduino, i2c

I am trying to make a GUI and I need my arduino to be I2C interfaced. I have used the arduinoIO package before but not with the I2C interface. After going through the Mathworks documentation, I found [this tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/examples/measure-temperature-from-i2c-device-on-arduino-hardware.html)  Can anyone tell me where I can find the complete documentation for the I2C library? I already checked the arduinoIO.m file and 'Libraries' doesn't even seem to be an input. Does MATLAB(R2014a) have an inbuilt ArduinoIO package? I have been using one from MATLAB File Exchange.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can see this a link [1](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/WireLibraryDetailedReference) but if you aren't sure what is I2C you can read this tutorial [I2C](http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/acatalog/I2C_Tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using R2104a or higher, you need to be using the [Arduino support package](http://uk.mathworks.com/hardware-support/arduino-matlab.html) from the main MathWorks web page, not the one from the File Exchange. Whether or not that includes I2C support, I don't know.